# Summation question basic

Tags: summation

After solving a probability question I ended up with the following:

$P(A)=\frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{5}{6})^{3n-2}$ limit between 1 and infinity but I'm unsure how to carry this on , I am familiar with summing $x^n$ to infinity for modulus X less than one . Sorry if this is a easy question, any help would be great thanks.

Comment: which are the limits of sum?

Comment: 1 to infinity not sure how to add limits to summation sorry

Comment: For the next time, \sum\limits_{lower bound}^{upper bound}

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo got it! thanks for your answer btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac16\sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{3x-2}&= \frac16 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{-2}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{3x}
\\\\&= \frac16 \cdot \frac{36}{25}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5^3}{6^3}\right)^{x}
\\\\&=\frac{6}{25}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{125}{216}\right)^{x}
\\\\&=\frac{6}{25}\cdot\frac{125}{216} \sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{125}{216}\right)^{x-1}
\\\\&=\frac{5}{36} \sum_{x=0}^\infty \left(\frac{125}{216}\right)^{x}
\end{align}
$$ by a change of index.

Hope you can finish it using
$$
\sum_{x=0}^\infty q^{x}=\frac 1{1-q},\quad|q|<1.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :), didn't spot that so dumb of me.

Comment: @Edwnhazard You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the fact that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty p^n=\frac{1}{1-p}$ if $|p|<1$.

Now,

$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{3n-2} &= \frac{1}{6}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{5}{6})^{3n}\right)(\frac{5}{6})^{-2}\\
&= \frac{6}{25} \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty [(\frac{5}{6})^3]^{n}\right)\\
\end{align*}$

Now put $p=(\frac{5}{6})^3$.

We have $\frac{6}{25}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty p^n=\frac{6}{25}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty p^n-p^0\right)=\frac{6}{25}\left(\frac{1}{1-p}-1\right)=\frac{6}{25}\frac{p}{1-p}=\frac{6}{25}\frac{(\frac{5}{6})^3}{1-(\frac{5}{6})^3}$

Answer (score 0):

It is a decreasing geometric progression with $q=\left(\frac56\right)^3<1$:
$$\frac16\sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{3x-2}=\frac16\left(\frac56+\left(\frac56\right)^4+\left(\frac56\right)^7+\cdots\right)=\frac16\cdot \frac{\frac56}{1-\left(\frac56\right)^3}=\frac{30}{91}.$$